# Root.plist setting.bundle old editor, where is it?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, settings.bundle

I have searched for the answer and I can not find it. How do I edit the settings.bundle in xcode 4.2?

I have found on this site you change to application.settings but that is not what I was looking for
This is the editor i have in xcode for the Root.plist:
[image]

and this is the old editor in xcode I was looking for.with the "+" to the right. Is this possible in xcode 4.2? Or did apple take this out?

Thank you so much, I am about ready to pull my hair out!!

[image]

Comment: Without looking, I believe it is in the project file at the top of the file browser on the left hand side; where the target and other settings are. But I may be wrong.

Comment: I looked but could not find it. I did a little more searching and someone said that the xcode version for Lion has the editor built back in xcode. I am running 10.6 with xcode 4.2.  More searching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor style has changed in Xcode 4. To add a new item, click on any item in the file (at the appropriate level for where you are trying to add it), and click the + that shows up and change the key and type as needed. The old editor with the + on the right is no more.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to try PlistEdit Pro. Not bad at all. Nice simple clean app. Use that for now. Thank you for the responses.